# What is DOM element?

Tags: dom

**What  is the meaning of DOM element in the following statements?**

[**Statement #1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes/1065453#1065453)

> You can add multiple classes to a
>   single DOM element.

[**Statement #2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes/1065477#1065477)

> The -- point is that inheritance in
>   CSS is done not through classes, but
>   through element hierarchies. So to
>   model inherited traits you need to
>   apply them to different levels of
>   elements in the DOM.

I know that DOM stands for  `Domain Object Model`. It seems to be synonym to API in the statements.

Comment: I think this will give some additional info http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html

Answer (score 122, accepted):

**Document** object model.
The DOM is the way Javascript sees its containing pages' data. It is an object that includes how the HTML/XHTML/XML is formatted, as well as the browser state.

A DOM element is something like a DIV, HTML, BODY element on a page. You can add classes to all of these using CSS, or interact with them using JS.

Answer (score 30):

It's actually Document Object Model. HTML is used to build the DOM which is an in-memory representation of the page (while closely related to HTML, they are not exactly the same thing). Things like CSS and Javascript interact with the DOM.

Answer (score 15):

If the statements are in the context of how CSS affects HTML then **DOM element** refers to an **HTML element**.

Answer (score 11):

To find out concept of DOM element it is essential to understand concept of Dynamic HTML and DOM. Everything is started from the time that requirements of all  stockholders of web pages are enhanced. They wanted the Web pages that can be more interactive, dynamic and lively. In addition, to reach this goal, developers required the tools and mechanisms that via them the presentation and content of each section of web page can be modified or manipulated. Therefore the concept of Dynamic HTML is created. To understand it, a great definition for Dynamic HTML is accessible in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_HTML):

> Dynamic HTML, or DHTML, is an umbrella term for a collection of
>   technologies used together to create interactive and animated websites
>   by using a combination of a static markup language (such as HTML), a
>   client-side scripting language (such as JavaScript), a presentation
>   definition language (such as CSS), and the Document Object Model
>   (DOM).

So, writing standard DHTML web pages are standardized in three fields, including client-side scripting language (such as JavaScript), a presentation definition language (such as CSS) and uniform programming interface(API) to access and modify the Web page (Document Object Model). This activity is performed by W3C and others. Also to solve the problem of cross browser, W3C tried to reach a general consensus (with different browser vendors) about scripts to access and manipulate HTML and XML documents via Document Object Model (DOM) as a standard application programming interface (API).

But the main question is that how they designed the structure of Document Object Model to meet their needs. Their solution was simple but wonderful. They used a hierarchical structure such as tree which at the root of the tree you can find document object, also each node is equivalent of a HTML elements (DOM element). This abstraction of your web page give you a great facility to access any HTML element, style sheets, and ... . To understand it better you can map each indent of your HTML code to each level of DOM tree. Please pay attention to this example:

Your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>...</p>
        <ul>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
        <table>
            <tr>...</tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

DOM Structure:

```
    document
      |    .    
    <html>    .
    /   \         .
 <head> <body>  styleSheets
        /  \  \
      <p> <ul> <table>
      /     \       \
    text    <li>    <tr>
```

So, each  node of this hierarchical structure (DOM tree) refers to a DOM element. [To learn more use tis reference](http://www.cs.kent.edu/~svirdi/Ebook/wdp/ch10.pdf)

Comment: Maybe, this should be expanded on Core DOM, XML DOM and HTML DOM. Also, example commands for manipulanting child and parent nodes (DOM elements) etc. - - Also, basic examples: in context of CSS, DOM element is HTML element etc.

Answer (score 9):

Document Object Model (DOM), a programming interface specification being developed by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C), lets a programmer create and modify HTML pages and XML documents as full-fledged program objects.

Answer (score 8):

DOM stands for Document Object Model. It is the W3C(World Wide Web Consortium) Standard. It define standard for accessing and manipulating HTML and XML document and The elements of DOM is head,title,body tag etc. So the answer of your first statement is

**Statement #1
You can add multiple classes to a single DOM element.**

Explanation : "div class="cssclass1 cssclass2 cssclass3"

Here  tag is element of DOM and i have applied multiple classes to DOM element.

Answer (score 7):

As per W3C: DOM permits programs and scripts to dynamically access and update the content, structure and style of XML or HTML documents.

DOM is composed of:

- set of objects/elements
- a structure of how these objects/elements can be combined
- and an interface to access and modify them

cheers

Answer (score 5):

DOM (Document Object Model) is a standard for accessing documents.

'When a web page is loaded, the browser creates a Document Object Model of the page.'

it's divided into 3 parts:

```
- Core DOM - standard model for all document types
- XML DOM - standard model for XML documents
- HTML DOM - standard model for HTML documents
```

To learn more, see:http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Answer (score 4):

See that your statements refer to "elements of the DOM", which are things such as the HTML tags (A, INPUT, etc). Thse statements simply mean that multiple CSS classes may be assigned to one such element.

Answer (score 1):

DOM is a logical model that can be implemented in any convenient manner.It is based on an object structure that closely resembles the structure of the documents it models.

For More Information on DOM :
[Click Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

When a web page is loaded, the browser creates a Document Object Model of the page.

The HTML DOM model is constructed as a tree of Objects:

[image]

With the object model, JavaScript gets all the power it needs to create dynamic HTML:

- JavaScript can change all the HTML elements in the page
- JavaScript can change all the HTML attributes in the page
- JavaScript can change all the CSS styles in the page
- JavaScript can remove existing HTML elements and attributes
- JavaScript can add new HTML elements and attributes
- JavaScript can react to all existing HTML events in the page
- JavaScript can create new HTML events on the page

[source](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)