# What is the main differences between DOM element and angular element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

That's the question, but specifically my problem is:

1. I can't execute `getComputedStyle` it keep yelling the first parameter is not type of element.
2. I can't access raw DOM property.
3. Often i can't see raw DOM property in web console.

I care more about my understanding rather than getting my code running.

Comment: Where is your code? and What is the issue?

Comment: sorry i asking about conceptual differences, so i didn't attach any code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Angular Element:**
>   If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or jqLite.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

> **DOM element**:
>   Document object model.
>   The DOM is the way Javascript sees its containing pages' data. It is an object that includes how the HTML/XHTML/XML is formatted, as well as the browser state.

A DOM element is something like a DIV, HTML, BODY element on a page. You can add classes to all and add style with respect to added classes using CSS, or interact with them using JS.
look at this answer
[What is DOM element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122437/what-is-dom-element)