# Inheriting from another style in a another style

Tags: html, css, inheritance

If have a style like this:

```
.Style1
{
   background-color:white;
}
```

And a second style like this:

```
.Style2
{
   border: black solid 1px;
}
```

How do I get `Style2` to have `Style1` as a base style?

Malcolm

Comment: This can be done in SCSS: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22770378/733092.

Answer (score 33):

```
.Style1, .Style2 {
     background-color:white;
}

.Style2 {
     border: black solid 1px;
}
```

This way `Style1` and `Style2` will both have the background set to white, and only `Style2` will also have a black border.

Answer (score 6):

There's no inheritance in CSS. The closest you can get to inheritance is by specifying 2 classes in your HTML elements:

```
<div class="Style1 Style2">..</div>
```

Or you can simply use the same style name:

```
.Style1 { background-color:white; }
.Style1 { border: black solid 1px; }
```

Now *Style1* will have both properties

Comment: This is right - you can specify multiple styles in the "class" attribute for an element.

Comment: This is twirks that don't directly simulate the inheritance behaviour. The answer from 10goto10 will work quite good as inheritance behaviour on the css class.

Answer (score 2):

the thing here is to simply use it as (example)

```
class="style1 style2"
```

this means the element will use the `style1` then `style2` (overriding `style1` with `style2` if any overlapping occurs e.g. if you use the same property in both the last one will be used).

Answer (score 1):

```
<... class="style2 style1" ..>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't really a way to do this.

You could of course make whatever element you wish to apply those style to include both class names `<div class="style1 style2">`

And the lack of this functionality is the reason there's been a rise in [OOCSS](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/02/28/object-oriented-css-grids-on-github/) (Object Oriented CSS). And frameworks such as [Less](http://lesscss.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
<span class="style1 style2">
```

or define

```
span { /* define base styles for all spans here */ }

span.style1 { /*inherits styles from span, and adds specific styles to that */ }
```

Using with

```
<p>Normal p text and <span>style</span>, <span class="style1">style 1 type text</span>.</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this method:

```
<div class="Style1">
   <div class="Style2">bla bla bla</div>
</div>
```