# how convert ".row class" or ".col class" into a unique class written into css/less boostrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, components

How I could create a "class" that contains .col configurations?

example (**NOT real, but is near to that I mean**):

html

`<div class="myClass">Hello World!</div>`

css/less

```
.myClass{
   col-xs-12;
   col-sm-offset-3, col-sm-6;
}
```

can you imaginate the potential to the use for the components?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Point one style class to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037187/point-one-style-class-to-another)

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#mixins

Answer (score 0):

In *less* this is called a [mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-mixins). Given the bootstrap template, you would do pretty much what you have above:

```
.myClass{
   col-xs-12;
   col-sm-offset-3;
   col-sm-6;
}
```

[More on mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature)