# ParseError:Unrecognised input in less while creating custom less file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to play around on bootstrap 3. I would like to create a custom less file (say custom_img.less) and import it to bootstrap.less. However, when I tried to compile the less to css, I got the error ParseError: UNrecognize input in xxxx. Please see the code below.

**custom_img.less**

```
.img-custom {
  @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
    width: 50%*@grid-float-breakpoint;
    height: 50%@grid-float-breakpoint;
  }
}
```

**Importing it in bootstrap.less**

```
@import "wells.less";
@import "close.less";
@import "custom_img.less";
```

The error is this- ParseError: Unrecognised input in XXXXX in

```
.img-custom {
```

What is wrong/missing? do I need to import something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**In your post you don't mention importing variables.less in bootstrap.less which defines @grid-float-breakpoint**

```
.img-custom {
  @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
    width: 0.5*@grid-float-breakpoint;
    height: 0.5*@grid-float-breakpoint;
  }
}
```

compiles into:

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .img-custom {
        width: 384px;
        height: 384px;
      }
    }
```

NOTE `50%*@grid-float-breakpoint;` gives 38400% and `50%@grid-float-breakpoint;`    compile into `50% 768px`

**update**

> why is that other bootstrap component does not have to import variable.less? like nav.less

I don't think its true, nav.less don't have to import variables.less. LESS throws an error and stop compiling if a variable or mixins is undefined. Also nav.less contains variables like `@border-radius-base`. Bootstrap's LESS files are intend to compile as `lessc bootstrap.less` bootstrap.less import required files s.a. variables.less and mixins.less. Of course you can comment out some components in bootstrap.less. Also see: [Bootstrap & LESS: importing mixins only as reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020633/bootstrap-less-importing-mixins-only-as-reference/)

Comment: Thank you @Bass, yeah, that makes sense, but why is that other bootstrap component does not have to import variable.less? like nav.less, there's no import directive on the file. I don't see any import there. Can you tell me why?