# How to reuse class on ID definition?

Tags: html, css

In the following code, is there a way to use the `.center` class in the CSS declaration rather than doing a `class=` in each div?  Each div should have a `margin:0 auto`.

CSS

```
.center {margin:0 auto;}
#first {width:400px; font-size:10px;}
#second{width:400px;text-align:center;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="center" id="first">This is the first line</div>
<div id="second">This is the first line</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ayK3J/

Comment: In pure css, no, but in sass, yes.

Comment: @blex - yes it is possible - see answer below

Comment: Some links: http://sass-lang.com/ , http://lesscss.org/

Comment: @ScottSelby Well that would apply to *all* divs, I don't know if OP wants that or only for certain divs... Anyway, what is important is for OP to find what he wants, so you might be right for him ;)

Comment: If the question is about whether it is possible to have each of the latter two rules reference the first one, then the answer is no, and the duplicate can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060405/is-it-possible-to-reference-one-css-selector-or-ruleset-within-another

Comment: Define what you mean by reusing a class. In general, you cannot use a class in CSS without using a class. You can, however, set a `class` attribute on an outer element just once (and use a suitable combined selector) instead of repeating such attributes.

Answer (score 8):

If you want each `div` to have `margin: 0 auto;`, then use a simple element selector like

```
div {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you want to center the `div` having IDs ONLY, then use *element[attr]* selector like

```
div[id] {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

But beware before using these; they are too general, and will lead to inconsistent results if your layout gets broader, so it's better to wrap an element around these `div` elements you want to apply `margin: 0 auto;` on and assign an ID to that(say, `#wrapper`) and than use a selector like

```
#wrapper > div {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or, using

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

should suffice as well...

---

Don't want to use a wrapper element? Modify your IDs like `#center-first`, `#center-second` and so on, then you can use *element[attr=val]* selector like

```
div[id^=center-] {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The above selector matches ANY IDS which start with a word `center` followed by a `-`

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Bejx/)</kbd>

Comment: I think what he asks for is a way to call the `.center` rule with all its declarations inside other rules. like SASS' `@extend` directive: `div { @extend .center }`

Comment: @AndersG Well, SASS isn't tagged so I gave the best I could with CSS only :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
#first,
#second {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```