# Editing all CSS rules relative to one id

Tags: css

I have a css and i want to put all the rules in css relative to an id.

For Example:
I have

```
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1px;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

And I have to make it like

```
#vn_space .clearfix {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1px;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Is there any simple method to put all css rules relative to one id instead of editing each rule

Comment: less or sass may help you.

Comment: You can do this easily in sass or less but not in vanilla CSS

Comment: CSS is a language, not a utility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance for second rule.

E.g. `clear: both` in `.clearfix` will apply to rule `#vn_space .clearfix`. So in `#vn_space .clearfix` you can omit anything that is same in rule `.clearfix`.

```css
.clearfix {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
#vm_space {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: green;
}
#vm_space .clearfix {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div id="vm_space">
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this any how then you can use it like

```js
$('div').css(["#vn_space", ".clearfix"]);
```

but i would not suggest it to prefer you can do this css with other way

here is ref link where i found

**[Is it possible to reference one CSS rule within another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060405/is-it-possible-to-reference-one-css-rule-within-another)**