# Is possible overwrite a css class with another css class

Tags: css, zk

I think this question is only related with css... but I will give you some context:

I am working with the zk framework and I have some comboboxes in my zul page... ZK render its components and turn them into html components with some predefined styles (css classes)... I can override those styles... but I want to override a whole css class with another so I can put my css class only in the components I want to change its style.

This is how a combobox is created:

[image: Combobox creation]

As you can see, it is turn into an `input` with a css class called z-combobox-input

If I overwrite that class directly, like this:

```
.z-combobox-input{
    border:1px solid #000;-webkit-border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;-moz-border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;-o-border-radius:3px 0 0     3px;-ms-border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;margin:0;padding:4px 5px;line-height:14px;background:#fff
}
```

It will afect every combobox in the page, as a result I get:

[image: css-rule afecting every component]

So I want to know if exist a way to do something like this:

```
.class-original{
    //some styles in here
}

.class-overriding{
    .class-original{
        //new styles in here
    }
}
```

So I can put my .class-overriding only in the components I need to change and not in every component of the same type.

```
<combobox id="newCombo" sclass="class-overriding" />
```

I made [this](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2l87mr9/1-Overriding-zk-combobox-style) fiddle if you want to try a solution.

I was seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4060405/5602069) question and apparently it is not possible... So: is there another way to achieve that?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I cannot use the id that is generated dinamically (in this case "vXgV3-real").

I can modify some properties from the combobox either by putting a css class or by using the tag `style`:

```
<combobox id="combo1" style="background: red" />
```

But I cannot change that border in particular, like this:

```
<combobox id="combo2" style="border:1px solid #000;-webkit-border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;-moz-border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;-o-border-radius:3px 0 0     3px;-ms-border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;margin:0;padding:4px 5px;line-height:14px;background:#fff"/>
```

Because when it is render (when zk change its component to html components) it turns in this:

[image: Result using tag style]

So, when zk change the `combobox` component to:

```
<span id="nZEQo" style="width:80%;" class="myCombo z-combobox">
    <input id="nZEQo-real" class="z-combobox-input" autocomplete="off" value="" type="text" style="width: 269px;">
    <a id="nZEQo-btn" class="z-combobox-button">
        <i class="z-combobox-icon z-icon-caret-down"></i>
    </a>
    <div id="nZEQo-pp" class="z-combobox-popup myCombo" style="display:none">
        <ul id="nZEQo-cave" class="z-combobox-content"></ul>
    </div>
</span>
```

It put random id's to the html components.

[Fiddle with this particular part](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3nmrpk4/1-Overriding-zk-combobox-style)

Some documentation:

[Customize Look and Feel of ZK Components Using CSS3 - Part 2](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2012/March/Customize_Look_and_Feel_of_ZK_Components_Using_CSS3_-_Part_2)

[ZK Component Reference>Input>Combobox](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Input/Combobox)

Comment: `ZK` has a few specific rules regarding styling. I took a few minutes to browse through it and updated my answer. You want to use `sclass` and `zclass` attributes on any element to add to or completely replace the default styling of that element. That's the basics.

Comment: I already replace the default style of the element... the problem @AndreiGheorghiu is that I need that some of that elements has the default look and the other mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** According to [`ZK documentation`](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/Theming_and_Styling/CSS_Classes_and_Styles) you could use `sclass` attribute to add classes to any element.

So, using the code I see in your screenshot...

```html
 <vbox>
   <combobox>
   <combobox sclass="whatever">
   <combobox>
 </vbox>
```

...you'll be able to use the following selector to specify rules for the `<combobox>`es you place `whatever` class on:

```css
.v-combobox.whatever .z-combobox-input {
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  margin:0; padding:4px 5px;
  line-height: 14px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

For more information use [`this guide`](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Style_Customization_Guide).

According to this guide, you should use `sclass` when you want to add to the default styles applied to an element and `zclass` attribute when you want to reset the default styles (that means only what you define in your custom class will apply, and not the default styling for that element).

---

**Initial answer:**

This is the most important principle in `CSS` and it's called ***specificity***.
Learning `CSS` means learning how you can use selectors and their specificity in order to apply rules selectively to some elements and not to others. It's what `CSS` is typically used for and it's totally possible.

Referencing an element by its id will be stronger (and hence override) any rules specified for any of its classes.

To understand specificity, I recommend [`this article`](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) as a starting point. You should also search for *specificity calculator* in your search engine of choice.

And in order to be able to use everything you learn about specificity you'll need to understand [`CSS Selectors`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and [`CSS Combinators`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp).

---

For your specific [ :) ] case, you probably want to use the element's `id` as selector to apply rules to that element only. Given the `id` from your first example, this will work:

```css
#vXgV3-real {
  /* the rules here will override the rules for .z-combobox-input
   * for the element with id="vXgV3-real" and only for that element 
   */
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  margin:0; padding:4px 5px;
  line-height: 14px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with this aproximation... the id "vXgV3-real" is auto-generated... the id I knew when I created the combobox was "combo1" `<combobox id="combo1" />`, and as you can see, zk translate this `combobox` to a span with other elements inside... (that's the real problem here... that I don't know (and can't trust in) the id of that input)

Comment: What happens when you specify an `id`? Have you read their documentation? This is a very basic need and everyone using their framework has it. They most certainly have a solution for it. You can always use an `.z-combobox:nth-child(x) .z-combobox-input{ /* rules here */}`, where `x` is the index of the element in its parent. Maybe it allows you to place an id on the parent. On `.z-combobox`. There has to be a convenient way to do it.

Comment: @Dazak, please do. And note `CSS` applies to the final markup, independently of what system you are using to generate that markup. So I'll be interested in the final markup, and so should you. You have to find ways to place `id`s or attributes on your elements and you can use those to set `CSS` rules for particular elements. A link to ZK documentation would be useful, too.

Comment: @Dazak Updated answer with (hopefully) sufficient information. Happy coding!

Comment: I appreciate your help... but it still do not work... I put your idea in [this fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/ile9mb/2-Overriding-zk-combobox-style)

Comment: Of course it doesn't. Instead of `v-combobox.whatever.z-combobox-input` you should use `.v-combobox.whatever .z-combobox-input`. It might look minor, but there's a huge difference. You just didn't take the time to understand what the ***empty space combinator*** does in CSS. You're also missing a `.` (dot) which, again makes a world of difference in `CSS`. Unfortunatelly, `CSS` is quite exact. Spaces matter. Dots matter. Almost every character matters.

Comment: That's right... it was my bad... sorry... and Thank you for your helpfull answer :)

Comment: @Dazak, there's another detail you should notice: while playing with their fiddle, I noticed `<style>` only applies if it's placed inside `<window>`. So please keep that in mind. [`See this`](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1feobbk/7-Overriding-zk-combobox-style). Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

When you can get ZK to render the element as

```
<input class="class-original class-overriding" />
```

you can use the following CSS to style only elements which do have both classes on them.

```
.class-overriding.class-original {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This will override the `background-color` property from `.class-original`. All properties you don't overwrite will be taken from `.class-original`-CSS

**Edit**: Just checked what ZK actually renders. It is (with the class names you provided in the fiddle)

```
<span class="another-class z-combobox">
    <input class="z-combobox-input" />
</span>
```

Given that, depending on whether you want to style the outer span or the inner input, you can use one of those CSS-Rules respectively:

```
.z-combobox.another-class {
  /*styles for the outer span*/
}
.z-combobox.another-class .z-combobox-input {
  /*styles for the outer span*/
}
```

The first one meaning "Everything with both classes (`z-combobox` and `another-class`)", the second one meaning "Everything with class `z-combobox-input` which is inside of something with both classes `z-combobox` and `another-class`

Comment: No, it does not work: [another fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/ile9mb/1-Overriding-zk-combobox-style)

Comment: I checked your fiddle and updated my answer accordingly