# Is it possible to reduce the number of css style names in Vaadin?

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin8

E.g., in the example below, is it possible to get rid of all the class names except my own, `w-grid`? Or at least reduce the number?

```
<div class="v-csslayout v-layout v-widget w-grid v-csslayout-w-grid
root_Z_Template v-csslayout-root_Z_Template v-has-width v-has-height"
style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="root_Z_Template">
```

Comment: Perhaps this thread is of use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060405/is-it-possible-to-reference-one-css-rule-within-another

Comment: Why do you want to replace them with your style only? Have a look at the method `setPrimaryStyleName`, maybe this is sufficient for you. However, defining `Grid` styles on your own feels like a lot of effort.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich It is a custom component based on `CssLayout`, the Vaadin style names are not relevant to it.