# What design philsophy led CSS away from class-level inheritance? (and reliance on @extend/@apply in sass)

Tags: css, css-selectors

It sounds like this is something that sass/less/mixins/jquery are required for right now.

What I'm looking to do is something like this:

```
.myClass {
    color: blue;
}

h1 {
    class: myClass;
}
```

I'm curious why this was not done already, given that CSS seems to be about inheritance/aggregation if nothing else.

Does it not make sense for some reason?

Or maybe it's just too complex?

Thanks!

...I don't know if this is the first '@extend' proposal, but it comes out because of its popularity in sass, apparently: http://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-extend-rule/

and there is an early discussion of the proposal in this list thread: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-houdini/2015Jan/0005.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to reference one CSS rule within another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060405/is-it-possible-to-reference-one-css-rule-within-another)

Comment: It does seem to answer a part of it, but not the core question -- which is, 'Is this feature coming in the new CSS?'  I was not 100% certain it could not be done without scripting, so your referenced question answers that part. The reason I ask is because, like other folks asking, it just seems like this is behavior/functionality that most of us would naturally want, and even expect, to have out of the box. Not a complaint - was just hoping to get some of the background on why CSS works like this.

Comment: You'll want to give your question a less speculative title. Speculative questions about the development of web standards are off-topic, and the actual question you're asking is about the existing design philosophy of CSS, which is right on the borderline but at least *somewhat* answerable with references (if they exist).

Comment: i'm assuming changing the title now will make it completely discombobulated, but i'll try it anyways.

Comment: Looks better. I'm still cautious as your question is sitting on 2 close votes and may well receive a third. It's still somewhat opinion-based - only a WG member would be able to provide an authoritative answer from *their* perspective. As to why it wasn't in CSS to begin with, honestly, I just doubt they really thought about this until Sass came along. Things were simpler back then.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is going to be a future CSS standard. But you can already do it with SASS and SCSS. Here is SCSS syntax:

```
.myClass {
    color: blue;
}

h1 {
    @extend .myClass;
    ...
}
```

Documentation: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend

Answer (score 0):

Well, in effect what you are trying to do is to make your CSS properties defined in the `.myClass` block, apply in your `h1` block, *(correct me if I'm wrong)*.

If that's what you meant, you can already do that by simply adding `myClass` to your `h1` tag like `<h1 class="myClass">Header</h1>` and in your CSS you would do this:

```css
.myClass {
  color: blue;
}

// or

h1.myClass {
  color: blue; // To only target h1 that have the 'myClass' class
}
```

> Will future CSS standard allow applying classes to elements in a style declaration?

Well as you can see we can already do that with HTML, so I doubt it.

Comment: The idea is to not have to redeclare the style attributes -- in this case, 'color:blue;'.

Comment: Well you only declare the `color: blue;` property once here, all you have to do after is putting your css class where you need them. But maybe I got your question wrong...

Comment: i think you got the gist of my question correct, but imagine a more complex example. i have 10 classes defined, called myClass1, myClass2, etc. I would like to be able to assign all those classes to my 'h1' elements by doing something like `h1{.myClass1 .myClass2 .myClass3}` -- and that's it. Each of those classes can have 1-100 rules.

Comment: So you're not talking about having the same behavior as @extend? Because otherwise if I understand it right, you're proposing to have the same feature as `<h1 class="myClass1 myClass2 myClass3>` but in CSS which would be redundant and confusing. And if you're indeed talking about something like @extend, well CSS inheritance is already here ^^.

Comment: yep, same behavior as @extend -- just without any extra tools like sass, less, etc.