# inherit from another class

Tags: css

how is it possible to make one class inherit from another in the CSS file?

```
input.btn {
    border:1px solid #23458c;
    background:url('gfx/layout.btn_bg.png');
    color:#f0f5fa;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:6px;
    padding:1px 6px 2px 6px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

input.btn_light {
    border:1px solid #717b8f;
    background:url('gfx/layout.btn_light_bg.png');
}
```

here I want `input.btn_light` to inherit from `input.btn`.. how is that possible to do in the CSS file?

### @vadiklk

```
input.btn {
    border:1px solid #23458c;
    background:url('gfx/layout.btn_bg.png');
    color:#f0f5fa;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:6px;
    padding:3px 6px 4px 6px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

input.btn_light {
    input.btn;
    border:1px solid #717b8f;
    background:url('gfx/layout.btn_light_bg.png');
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a CSS class inherit one or more other classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Give the HTML element both classes:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn_light" value="Action" />
```

Comment: +1 for just using CSS. What's the point in using something else when CSS does the job? It's like you are somehow _Cascading_ those _Styles_ :-)

Comment: Agreed, LESS and Sass are great, but aren't adding anything in this case (and probably 95% of other cases...)

Answer (score 3):

According to: http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/inheritance/ it is not possible and needed.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, you can also do the following with your CSS. The difference being that instead of using multiple class names where it will be *used*, this way uses multiple class names in the CSS to say "use this style *and* this style". Then, the reference (the input button in this case) only uses one class name.

In the end, it accomplishes the same thing as the accepted answer.

**Note:** I changed the value of the borders because I wanted to use values that were less subtle for the snippet.

```css
input.btn,
input.btn_light {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: url('gfx/layout.btn_bg.png');
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 6px;
  padding: 1px 6px 2px 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input.btn_light {
  border: 2px solid green;
  background: url('gfx/layout.btn_light_bg.png');
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="Regular">
  <br>
  <input type="button" class="btn_light" value="Light">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

SCSS/SASS example:

HTML

```
<h1><span class='section-title'>Some heading!</span></h1>
<h2><span class='section-title'>Some heading!</span></h2>
<h3><span class='section-title'>Some heading!</span></h3>
<h4><span class='section-title'>Some heading!</span></h4>
<h5><span class='section-title'>Some heading!</span></h5>
<h6><span class='section-title'>Some heading!</span></h6>
```

SCSS

```
// This will style every .section-title element within
// a heading the same as the heading.
.section-title {
  h1 & { @extend h1; }
  h2 & { @extend h2; }
  h3 & { @extend h3; }
  h4 & { @extend h4; }
  h5 & { @extend h5; }
  h6 & { @extend h6; }
}
```