# CSS style declaration reusage

Tags: css

Lets say I have in my CSS a color definitions:

```
.headerColor   { background-color: #a6c9e2; }
```

Now I would also like to define a CSS definition that uses .headerColor:

```
.header        { padding-left: 2px; }
```

On the CSS level, how can I inherit .header from .headerColor? 
I know I can place the two styles on the HTML element (class='header headerColor'), but how can I assign .header to my HTML element and have it pull its parent styles?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [inherit from another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175633/inherit-from-another-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
.headerColor, .header   { background-color: #a6c9e2; }
.header                 { padding-left: 2px; }
```

Now, you just need to set `class="header"` in HTML.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have a quick question. Lets sayI define a color: .blueColor { color: #3b5ae0; }.  Now i would like to reference this color when creating css's for background-color or border-color? For example. .editor { background-color: ??(.blueColor) }

Comment: Then you will need `lesscss.org`. But usually I just copy and paste the color.