# Reuse CSS class

Tags: css

I should have asked this in my previous question ([CSS style declaration reusage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898852/css-style-declaration-reusage)), but I didn't think of it at the time. Since that question is answered, I'll start a new one.

I am trying to create color palette in CSS that will be used through out my application. 
For example:

```
.blue  { color: #434544; }
.green { color: #G99933; }
```

I do not want to define colors anywhere else in my CSS. The problem I am running into is how do i use the `.blue` style when, for example, I need a `background-color` definition? Take a look at this:

```
.editor { background-color: #434544 }
```

I want to reference back to the `.blue` style instead of defining it here again.  How can I do that?

**UPDATE**
I found the perfect solution for my question: 
Chirpy -> http://chirpy.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to do this in native CSS. You should look into [pre-processing your CSS](http://css-tricks.com/musings-on-preprocessing/), since all those pre-processors have support for variables.

Here's what it looks like using (scss-flavored) SASS:

```css
$blue: #434544;
$green: #G99933;

.blue  { color: $blue; }
.green { color: $green; }

.editor { background-color: $blue }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Let me go research it. Thanks

Comment: @BlueChameleon: If this is your accepted answer, please designate it as such.

Comment: I will. It wont let me for another 4 minutes.