# How do I use the alignment of one class and the font of another?

Tags: html, css

I have to modify a website that another developer wrote.

I need the font and size from one class, but I need the formatting from another.

html:

```
 <div class="box1">
     <div class="box2">
         <p class="p1">
            The text I need printed
         </p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

css:

```
.box1
{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 15px;
}

.box1 p.p1
{
    font-size:15px;
    color:#ff00ff;
    line-height:22px;
}

    ...

.box2
{
    padding:10px;
}

.box2 p.p1
{
    font-size:12px;
    color:#ff0000;
    line-height:22px;
}
```

How do I use p1 from box1 while keeping the alignment the same?  I would rather not define a new .box2 p.p2 unless that is the only way.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but did you try just removing the `.box2 p.p1` rule?

Comment: It is using the p1 rule from box2.  Is there a clean way to use the p1 rule from box1?

Comment: Refer:

[Can a CSS class inherit one or more other classes?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes

Comment: Did you try what I said in the comment above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .box1
            {
                float:left;
                width:500px;
                padding:10px 0px 10px 15px;
            }
            .box1 .box2 p.p1
            {
                font-size:15px;
                color:#ff00ff;
                line-height:22px;
            }
            .box2
            {
                padding:10px;
            }
            .box2 p.p1
            {
                font-size:12px;
                color:#ff0000;
                line-height:22px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box1">
            <div class="box2">
                <p class="p1">The text I need printed</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Here's a demo** - http://jsfiddle.net/fedev/ZwrfV/

**UPDATED**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .box1
            {
                float:left;
                width:500px;
                padding:10px 0px 10px 15px;
            }
            .box1 p.p1, .box1 .box2 p.p1
            {
                font-size:15px;
                color:#ff00ff;
                line-height:22px;
            }
            .box2
            {
                padding:10px;
            }
            .box2 p.p1
            {
                font-size:12px;
                color:#ff0000;
                line-height:22px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box1">
                        <p class="p1">The text I need printed under box 1</p>
            <div class="box2">
                <p class="p1">The text I need printed under box 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Another demo** - http://jsfiddle.net/fedev/M9mWN/

Comment: This almost worked!  "The text I need printed" is correct.  And other texts where box2 p.p1 are in the other format.  The only problem is other texts that were under box1 p.p1 are not formatted.  How do I keep that formatting?  Thanks

Comment: Please see under *UPDATED*. I created another demo for you.

Answer (score 1):

From the examples you posted, I don't think you need multiple classes here (as others are suggesting). Do you realize what is going on? Your paragraph is being applied both paragraph rules you have defined, `.box1 p.p1` **and** `.box2 p.p1`. Since the latter overwrites all properties from the former, those are the styles you see.

**I think all you need to do is remove the second rule (`.box2 p.p1`) entirely**.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't remove .box2 p.p1 because it is used in other places.

Comment: Can you move it before the other rule? Will that negatively affect other parts too?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely clear on what you are trying to accomplish, but the basic answer to your question (about basically needing to combine two classes) is that you can have an element with more than one class, just separate them by spaces

```
class="class1 class2 ...."
```