# Is there a way to add jquery ui classes into my own css file per element

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

is there a way to add jquery ui classes into my own css file per element, IE:

```
       input { 
               ui-corner-all  /*  <- JQuery UI class */ 

              }
```

as opposed to adding the class to every input, IE:

```
       <input name="myinput" type="text" class="ui-corner-all"  value="" />
```

Comment: Are you meaning that you would like to just apply the ui-corner-all class attributes directly to `input` such that you can remove the class name from the actual input element?

Comment: You could duplicate the CSS definition from the UI css file and put it in your own css file, applied to any element you want. Would that work for you?

Comment: You can check out LESS: here a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `.addClass` method to add a class to elements at any time, including page load, such as:

```
$(function() {
  $(input).addClass('ui-corner-all');
});
```

This would add the `ui-corner-all` class to every input element in the html when the page loads. If you would like to select only certain elements on the page, use a more specific selection, such as:

```
$(function() {
  $('#myInput').addClass('ui-corner-all');
});
```

This will add the `ui-corner-all` class to all of the elements on the page that have the ID of `myInput`.

Comment: Granted, this is not what I was asking for, it worked better for me! Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [LESS](http://lesscss.org), here is a very similar question on SO [Can a CSS class inherit one or more other classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes)

LESS is an extension for CSS a great level of abstraction with variables, nested rules, function, operations, etc

Comment: how is the browser compatibility with your answer compaired to the javascript answer below?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into checking out Sass. This will give you the option to extend css classes to your own classes via @extend.

[This is a handy Sass + Compass video](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/88-intro-to-compass-sass/)

[Then after you can do this](http://iain.nl/using-sass-with-jquery-ui)

This way, you don't have to depend on javascript to add classes. It's all done through css.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a preprocessor like LESS to achieve this. You would have to save your `ui.css` as `ui.less` and then you could do something like this:

```
@import url(ui.less);

input {
  .ui-corner-all;
}
```

After compilation of your less to css, it would take all the styles of the `ui-corners-all` class and apply them to your inputs. And that is just one of the many advantages of using a css preprocessor. It is really worth looking into and is not very hard to learn if you are familiar with css. You can find more info here: http://lesscss.org/