# Defining a CSS which inherits from another

Tags: css

Is it possible to create a CSS specifying it should inherit from another one?
For example I want single-match-header to inhert from normal-text

```
.normal-text {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}    

.single-match-header {
    background-color: #666666;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes

Comment: The answer is referenced in @Ranveer's link, but it bears repeating: [CSS LESS](http://lesscss.org/).