# How to reuse css class content in another class without copying?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use existing css class as content in another class ?

I mean something like:

```css
/* Contained in some library: */
.class1 { text-indent: 100 }
```

```html
/* I can not change this: */
<span class="class2">
```

The definition for `class2` is also contained in another library. So I can not change it directly.

```css
/* But I want to do something like that in my CSS file: */
.class2 { .class1 }
```

I know it is not possible in that form. But maybe one can use some trick to achieve the behaviour without copying of the content of `class1`? I need this because I want to redefine class with content from another CSS class. Our project uses jQuery as well, but I would do it rather with CSS.

**EDIT**: I should explain more, I could not change how `.class1` is defined, because this class is in a library, and I could not change mark up on span class.

Comment: There is no such thing as a CSS class. HTML has classes. CSS has class selectors (but you appear to be talking about rule-sets).

Comment: add class1 to class2 elements and define specific CSS rules to override for elements having both classes: `.class1.class2 {...}`

Comment: @A.Wolff I can not change the class attribute of elements, because they are generated from framework. I can only define my own CSS file.

Comment: @Tony but you can still use js/jq to add class to specific elements: `$(function(){$('.class2').addClass('class1')});` Or i'm missing something??? Then just set a specifc CSS rule for these elements like posted in my previous comment

Comment: Thank you, yes this is the real option, if I could not  do it with pure CSS.

Comment: with all the restrictions explained.. @A.Wolff's comment is the logical route..

Comment: I Hope This may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes

Answer (score 17):

It is imposible to do in standard CSS what you are commenting, as there is not pure inheritance.

Despite it doesn't apply with your code restrictions, this is the closer way to do it:

```
    .class1, .class2 { text-indent: 100 }

    .class2 { 
            /* Styles you want to have only in class 2 */
    }

    <span class="class2" />
```

On the other hand, as @A. Wolff has pointed out, you can still use js/jq to add class to specific elements: $(function(){$('.class2').addClass('class1')}); Then just set a specifc CSS rule for these elements.

In case you don't want to use JS, for something like that you'd need to use SASS or similar, which "compiles" to CSS.

Comment: you need to add a comma after .class1

Comment: This still works today, FYI.  I tested it out.  Thanks

Answer (score 14):

CSS has no means to reference one rule-set from another.

Your options include:

*Using multiple selectors for things with common rules*

```
.menu,
.nav {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.nav {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

*Using multiple classes on a single element*

```
.menu {
     font-weight: bold;
}

.nav {
     display: inline-block;
}

<li class="menu nav">
```

---

*Generating your CSS programatically*

For example, with [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

```
@mixin menu {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    @include menu;
}
```

Comment: Cool answer, but I have more strict requirements. please check updated question.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) to do this. It's a very good tool and do some improvements to your CSS development.

Take a look at theirs documentation, it's very nice. About the compilers, I use [Koala](http://koala-app.com/) and recommend it.

Comment: Thank you, but I can not use Less, please check updated question.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned in one comment that you cannot use LESS, but I think perhaps you misunderstand how LESS (or another preprocessor) could help you. That is, you have not given any reason that I can see why you cannot use it (even in your update). As I understand your problem, you have the following parameters:

1. Cannot change html
2. Cannot change the css file that defines `.class1`.
3. You can change the css file that defines `.class2`.

If the above is correct, then here is how you use LESS (version 1.5+). You make your file defining `.class2` a `.less` file. Then, to keep it clean, I believe you are going to have to do a two step process (it may be you can do step 2 without step 1).

**Step One: Make the CSS into LESS**

Create a file, let's say `CSStoLESS.less` and put this in it:

```
@import (less) /path/to/your/your-css-defining-class1.css;
```

This will import the css and make the processor consider it as LESS code. It is possible that the next step does that as well, I have not had opportunity to test it out.

**Step Two: Use that file as reference in your LESS**

By doing this in your `.less` file defining `.class2`:

```
@import (reference) /path/to/your/CSStoLESS.less;

.class2 { .class1; }
```

You are importing the previous css file that has been converted to less as reference only. This prevents you from getting duplicate selectors for `.class1` or anything else contained in your original css file. Now you can use an inclusion of `.class1` just like you show in your question to make the properties of `.class1` become that of `.class2`.

It may be that this alone works:

```
@import (reference) /path/to/your/your-css-defining-class1.css;

.class2 { .class1; }
```

What I don't know is if the `(reference)` inclusion also defaults to making `.css` into LESS code like the `(less)` inclusion typecasting does in step one. I need to research this out more. If so, then it is a one-step, not a two-step process.

Comment: Thank you. I can not change the css file, that defines .class2 (item 3). But I hope I could replace (override)  the .class2 in my css file that comes after. And yes you are right I've not used less so far. Does Less compile the css for every request?

Comment: @Tony: I see. The cascade of CSS is overriding `.class2`. Ok, the same principle in my answer still applies, just that you are making your override file using the `.class1` as a LESS mixin. LESS is designed to be a preprocessor, so normally compiling is done before any request, and the request itself is for the output css file that was created by LESS. This should be fine if `.class1` does not change often. If it potentially changes per request, then you would have to run LESS client side (which is not recommended for speed purposes, but if you are just defining one class, that may be okay).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possoble.

Write:

```
.class1,.class2 {text-indent:100;}
.class1{color:red;}
.class2{font-size:30px;}
```

[**More info here.**](http://www.cssnewbie.com/css-rules-multiplicity/#.Up8Z3nV8DeQ)

Comment: @downvoter, please have courtesy to comment down the reason.

Comment: How is your answer any different than the answer of @Chexpir ?

Comment: @Ghazali we both posted at same time. You may check the timestamp and it's a co incident

Comment: Didn't notice. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to redeclare `class1` just below your custom css ends and override it with the values that you are looking for. This way, the inherited values, that you cannot change + the values that you need to incorporate, both shall apply.

Answer (score 1):

Others mentioned SASS and LESS. Here's the solution of Stylus:

```
.class1
  text-indent: 100

.class2
  @extend .class1
```

Comment: It works with SCSS but I have no idea how to use it in existing projects

Answer (score 1):

I think OP has similar issue that I'm facing.

In my case, i'm building a local interface and I want to allow user to switch themes; icon themes may be phosphoricons or Font Awesome or Google material... Yes, one can load one or other CSS for using those iconsets, but the way they are applied differ. For example, with phosporicons you'd go...

```
<a href="/" class="ph-duotone ph-house"><!-- HOME icon --></a>
```

but with font awesome...

```
<a href="/" class="fas fa-home"><!-- HOME icon --></a>
```

but with google material...

```
<a href="/" class="material-icons">home</i></a>
```

the idea would be creating some "meta" css that would allow code to be just

```
<a href="/" class="home"></i></a>
```

because:

1. you cannot modify all HTML code everytime user wants to change icons
2. you cannot modify Font awesome, phosphoricons for creating common words (okay, you can, but it would be tedious as hell... i'm using just a small subset)

At the moment, my (bad) solution is fixing by code, as I'm using flask to serve pages. Just defined a dict (dinamically changed per user request) such as

```
iconset = {'home': 'ph-duotone ph-house'}
```

and then passed it to jinja template and used as

```
<a href="/" class="{{ iconset['home'] }}"><!-- HOME icon --></a>
```

Okay, it works, and I don't need to change everything allways, just replacing the iconset words per flask variables. But it's ugly as hell. Searching for a CSS-only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can define 2 classes in this way

```
.class1, .class2 { text-indent: 100 }
```

And it will work for you

Moreover if you want to ad some more in class2 then you can define it

```
.class2 { /*whatever you want here*/ }
```

Comment: Thank you, but that is not an option. Please check updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want whatever is in `.class1` plus some extra properties in `.class2`

One way is to simply apply both classes to the element you want..

```
<span class="class1 class2" />
```

another is to name both classes when setting the properties

```
.class1, .class2 {text-indent: 100}

.class2{/*extra properties here*/}
```

Comment: @Tony I am sure that answer you need. And this is a greath asnwer!

Comment: @Dimi not really, because I cannot change `<span class="class1" />` to `<span class="class1 class2" />`. This html is generated not by me.