# How to get the computed (or the specified) value for a CSS property (not the resolved or used value) with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am looking for eg. "width: min-content" not "width: 210px" or "green" instead of "rgb(0,255,0)". So `$(elem).css("width")` is not what I am searching for.

I take the naming  (specified or computed) from MDN

> The **specified** value of a CSS property is the value
> **it receives from the document's style sheet**. The specified value for a given property
> is determined according to the following rules:  ...
>
> The **computed** value of a CSS property is the value that is transferred
> from parent to child **during inheritance**. It is calculated from the
> specified value by: ...

vs.:

> The **resolved value** of a CSS property is the value returned by
> getComputedStyle().
>
> For most properties, it is the computed value, but for a few legacy
> properties (including width and height), **it is** **instead the used value**.
>
> The **used value** of a CSS property is its value after all calculations
> have been performed on the computed value.

One reason is, that I am overworking some layouts to (almost) only implicit sizes, and warn myself if I missed an explicit width in CSS files.

An other is, that I want to help grid to display a variable count of elements to place it in a more 'square' manner, depending on the space available. Therefore I need to know if the spec for grid items is min- or max-content.

Edit: Walking through styles sheets can't be a solution - that would mean to program the whole inheritance of CSS ...

Comment: IRRC, your only real options in JS are to use `getComputedStyle()` for computed styles (or resolved values, as you defined) or the `style` property on an element.

Comment: what about using CSS flexbox. are you looking something like this [https://jsfiddle.net/eptzoqra/](https://jsfiddle.net/eptzoqra/)

Comment: @AndroidNoobie: thx, but it is not "my definition"; I took it from MDN. It is often mixed up: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resolved_value

Comment: Yes, I know, I just meant using the definitions you provided.

Comment: @DeepuReghunath: although its only one reason for the question: I use Flex at the moment; what I want to program  is a more intelligent way of spreading up: in a short: make 2 rows of 4 if not all 8 fit in only one row. not 7 and 1. (or 3 rows  3/3/2)
But this question is about getting  specified  css values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed css variables  => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

```js
const Root     = document.documentElement
    , gRoot    = getComputedStyle(Root)
    , cssVname = '--min-content'
    , myInput  = document.querySelector('#my-input')

var  currentVal = parseInt( gRoot.getPropertyValue(cssVname) )

myInput.value = currentVal

myInput.oninput =_=>
  {
  currentVal = myInput.valueAsNumber
  Root.style.setProperty(cssVname, `${currentVal}px`)
  }
```

```css
:root {
  --min-content: 210px;
}

div {
  height: 20px;
  width: var(--min-content);
  background-color : rgb(27, 117, 90);
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>

<input id="my-input" type="number" min="100" max="300" step="10" value="210">
```

you can also use themes => [How to over ride css prefers-color-scheme setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300132/how-to-over-ride-css-prefers-color-scheme-setting/56550819#56550819)