# Overwrite SASS colors, e.g with data-attributes

Tags: html, sass, styling

I'm trying to achieve something similar like here: [How to override css prefers-color-scheme setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300132/how-to-override-css-prefers-color-scheme-setting), with the difference that I'm using SCSS.

There are some top-level variables defined:

```
$content-primary: #000000;
$content-secondary: #FFFFFF;
```

I want to overwrite those values, depending on the information on the client (`localStorage`, media query). I started by setting the data-attribute to the `html` element, e.g. `document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");`.

```
// Some SCSS magic here checking data attributes
// When data-theme="dark" is set, the following should be applied:
$content-primary: #F1F1F1;
$content-secondary: #222222;
```

I've tried to use the same logic as in the related question, but that does not work.

```
[data-theme="dark"] {
    $content-primary: #F1F1F1;
    $content-secondary: #222222;
}
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done theming on a project and used `!default`
[Click here to read documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#default-values)

But seeing what you want to do, I suggest you to use native CSS `var(--content-primary)`

This Basic CSS variables can be overwritten not only based on attribute/class/parent etc. But also based on Media Query which makes them an incredible versatile tool.

Comment: Thank you.
I solved it with 
`:root {
    --content-primary: #000000;
    --content-secondary: #616161;
}

$content-primary: var(--content-primary);
$content-secondary: var(--content-secondary);

[data-theme=dark] {
    --content-primary: #F1F1F1;
    --content-secondary: #999999;
}
`.
That way I can keep the variables I have at other places in my `.scss` files.
Just out of curiosity... Is this an improper solution, i.e. is `!default` cleaner?

Comment: `!default` is definitely cleaner, especially if you want to have two separate files for color themes, e.g. default Light theme in base.light.scss with `!default`, and in base.dark.scss you just import there base.light.scss and redefine those colors, simple as that. But then you wont have dynamically switching colors based on a selector.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback!
I definitely want to give the users the possibility to switch between dark and light theme.