# SASS: Media query and id using same parameters

Tags: css, sass

I have a simple SASS code that may be working like when the user has on his device set preferred color scheme **dark** the parameters from **%dark-theme** will extend to `<body>` and also when the user has preferred color scheme **light** the **%light-theme** will be extended instead of **%dark-theme** to `<body>`.

The same parameters which are used in **%dark-theme** and **%light-theme** may be extended on `<body>` when `<body>` have set id to **#switched-dark-mode** or **#switched-light-mode**. This IDs are set by Javascript after user switch the theme color.

Is there any solution to how I can make my SCSS clear and parameters which are used in @extends write only one time and use them in media query and also in ID selector?

**MY CODE:**

```
%dark-theme {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}

%light-theme {
    background: white;
    color: black;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    body {
        @extend %dark-theme;
    }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    body {
        @extend %light-theme;
    }
}

body {
    &#switched-dark-mode {
        @extend %dark-theme;
    }

    &#switched-light-mode {
        @extend %light-theme;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot specify multiple selectors when using `@media` queries in SCSS (or at least to my knowledge). What you have already is a good solution.

One workaround you could try would be to use the "prefers-color-scheme" query in JavaScript when you load the page to apply the appropriate ID on the `body` element, which would allow you to remove the two `@media` queries from your SCSS code.

That means you could just move the styles defined in `%dark-theme` and `%light-theme` into the appropriate body selector.

Check out this post for reference and other solutions:

[How to override css prefers-color-scheme setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300132/how-to-override-css-prefers-color-scheme-setting)