# Dark mode / light mode / default taken from system preferences: possible without lots of CSS duplication?

Tags: css

I'm in the process of implementing dark mode on my site.  It's important to me to offer the user three options:

- implicit dark mode
- implicit light mode
- follow the set system preference

The code suggested at https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-dark-mode-on-the-web/#overriding-os-settings contains lots of duplication:

```
/* Default colors */
body {
  --text-color: #222;
  --bkg-color: #fff;
}
/* Dark theme colors */
body.dark-theme {
  --text-color: #eee;
  --bkg-color: #121212;
}

/* Styles for users who prefer dark mode at the OS level */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  /* defaults to dark theme */
  body { 
    --text-color: #eee;
    --bkg-color: #121212;
  }
  /* Override dark mode with light mode styles if the user decides to swap */
  body.light-theme {
    --text-color: #222;
    --bkg-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

This only becomes more and more unmanageable as more custom properties get added.

Is there a better way?  I actually already run my CSS through a PHP preprocessor (with long-expires caching) that I started using a decade ago when UA-prefixing All The Things was *de rigeur* and necessary, so I can use PHP to do the duplication for me.  But it still feels like a lot of wasted bytes to send down the wire.

Is there a better solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to combine media queries with CSS class-rules.
The deduplication can be done with Sass or PHP useing a `@mixin` or a `$variable`

There is a small optimization to save some bytes being transfered,
you only have to duplicate the Dark theme. and make the light mode the default/fallback:

```
/* Light theme */
body, body.light {
  --text-color: #222;
  --bkg-color: #fff;
}
/* Dark theme */
body.dark {
  --text-color: #eee;
  --bkg-color: #121212;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  /* dark theme */
  body { 
    --text-color: #eee;
    --bkg-color: #121212;
  }
}
```

To deduplicate the list of color variables (because this list would be larger in reality) In Sass it would look like this:

```
@mixin light-theme {
  --text-color: #222;
  --bkg-color: #fff;
}
@mixin dark-theme {
  --text-color: #eee;
  --bkg-color: #121212;
}

body, body.light {
    @include light-theme;
}
body.dark {
    @include dark-theme;
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    body{
        @include dark-theme;
    }
}
```

If you realy don't want to duplicate any CSS you CAN use Javascript:
You need to remove the `@media-query` part and  toggle the `dark` class based on OS preference:

```
const prefersColorQuery = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)'),
  changeTheme = e => {
    document.body.classList[e.matches ? 'add':'remove']('dark')
  }
  
changeTheme(prefersColorQuery);
prefersColorQuery.addEventListener('change', changeTheme);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push even further the use of variables:

```css
:root {
  --text-for-light: #222;
  --bkg-for-light: #fff;
  --text-for-dark: #eee;
  --bkg-for-dark: #121212;
}

/* Default colors */
body {
  --text-color: var(--text-for-light);
  --bkg-color: var(--bkg-for-light);
}

/* Dark theme colors */
body.dark-theme {
  --text-color: var(--text-for-dark);
  --bkg-color: var(--bkg-for-dark);
}

/* Styles for users who prefer dark mode at the OS level */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  /* defaults to dark theme */
  body { 
    --text-color: var(--text-for-dark);
    --bkg-color: var(--bkg-for-dark);
  }
  /* Override dark mode with light mode styles if the user decides to swap */
  body.light-theme {
    --text-color: var(--text-for-light);
    --bkg-color: var(--bkg-for-light);
  }
}
```

This way, your variables are only defined in one place.

Comment: That is arguably an improvement, but there's still a lot of duplication (lines 8->18 vs lines 22->32).  I certainly like how if I decided to change a variable I only have to change it in one place, but it definitely still leaves a lot to be desired.  I suspect this is as good as it gets though?

Comment: If you want that to not be duplicated, don't use CSS, use a preprocessor.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, using a PHP array of arrays `['--propName', 'lightValue', 'darkValue']` and then using four PHP loops to write them out.  I just hoped there was a better way, a clever combination of selectors/media queries that would remove the duplication.  But if there is, I can't see it.

Comment: Try SCSS, SASS or something like that, it like "programmable CSS".

Comment: I'm lightly familiar with them, but have never used them.  I'll try to add them to my repertoire one day, but as a sole full-stack dev running my own business I already feel pretty thin!