# Is it possible to trigger css prefers-color-scheme in js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I using components who change their ui base on `@media (prefers-color-scheme: ...)` query media in css.

Is it possible to trigger the change using javascript api?

Something like this possible and it trigger this query media rule in the css?

```
 window.change('prefers-color-scheme', 'dark');
```

Comment: if you want to change the color yourself, then dont use the user preferences.

Comment: First item in google "js change prefers-color-scheme" search - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300132/. Does it answer your question?

Comment: no, I don't want to change the `prefers-color-scheme`, but to trigger it. 
it's not the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you cannot change `prefers-color-scheme`. `prefers-color-scheme` is the user value for dark mode, set in the OS settings.

Read more about `prefers-color-scheme` on [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme)

If you want, you can create a custom dark mode toggle. You can have a CSS class `dark` that applies dark mode styles.

```js
const dark = true;

if (dark) {
    document.body.classList.add('dark');
}
```