Button to switch the user's dark mode browser preference?
I want to provide a "dark mode" switch on a website. That would be easy by using some CSS.
But then: Modern browsers can already tell the website that they want to use a dark mode (prefers-color-scheme). And I can also react to that via CSS.
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    html {
        filter: grayscale(0.75) invert(1) contrast(1);
    }
}

My problem is: I do not want these mechanisms (button on the website and browser preference) to collide. And I need the button on the website, because many users don't know that their browser can change the preference.
Is there any mechanism that would allow a website to provide a button that would change the browser preference?
I fully understand that you would usually not want to allow websites to do something like "change my preferences", however, it seems like a good idea regarding the prefers-color-scheme.

The browser can delegate this preference to the operating system. Would you then expect to change even the operating system preference with the website button? And imagine that the operating system preference is stored in a user's cloud account. I believe that such a button cannot meet the expectations it raises.

is this your answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300132/how-to-override-css-prefers-color-scheme-setting

This answer - in a nutshell - says to start with the browser setting and override it for the current page, if the button is pressed. Not actually my ideal idea, but still an approach should the global switch not be possible. Thank you.

TBH: If your "ideal idea" is to give a website more control than the user, your ideals are wrong. It's a good idea to respect your user's preferences, not to control/change them.

Unfortunately, there is no way for the website to change users' preferences in the browser regarding prefers-color-scheme directly that would of course be a security and privacy concern. you can do a solution that manually overrides while respecting the user's initial preference.

This is a great reference on implementing a dark mode switch.
The concept is that you:

provide a mode switch which operates within the website, and persist the value of the switch in session storage or local storage so that the mode stays the same as the user browses from page to page;

listen for any changes to the OS dark mode setting and adjust the local setting to match;

if there is no mode in session storage or local storage, such as would happen when a user visits the site for the first time, then read the OS dark mode setting and use that as the initial setting.



I prefer a three-way choice for the user:

Use light mode for this page
Use dark mode for this page
Follow the browser/OS setting.

Changes to the browser/OS setting are then ignored if the user has explicitly chosen light or dark mode.


/* This code block simulates localStorage in the sandbox in which the snippet runs. */
let _darkmode;
const localStorage = {
  getItem(prop) {
    return _darkmode;
  },
  setItem(prop, value) {
    _darkmode = value;
  }
};
/* Omit everything above this line in production. */

function auto() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("darkmode") === "auto") {
    if (darkmode.matches)
      document.body.classList.add("darkmode");
    else document.body.classList.remove("darkmode");
  }
}

function explicit() {
  const value = document.querySelector("select").value;
  localStorage.setItem("darkmode", value);
  switch (value) {
    case "auto":
      auto();
      break;
    case "on":
      document.body.classList.add("darkmode");
      break;
    default:
      document.body.classList.remove("darkmode");
  }
}
document.querySelector("select").value =
  localStorage.getItem("darkmode") || "off";
const darkmode = matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
darkmode.addEventListener("change", auto);
explicit();
body.darkmode div {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
<div>Text</div>
<select onchange="explicit()">
  <option value="off">Light</option>
  <option value="on">Dark</option>
  <option value="auto">Auto</option>
</select>



