# How to centrally assign a same CSS class to multiple elements, such as when using frameworks like Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just started studying web development and tried a couple of front-end frameworks such as Bootstrap, 960 and Foundation.

For example with Bootstrap, when several images are to be universally assigned a same set of classes, for now I find it necessary that all these classes be placed within each elements individually, such as :

```
<div id="foo" class="container">
    <img src="img1.jpg" class="thumbnail img-responsive etc etc"/>
    <img src="img2.jpg" class="thumbnail img-responsive etc etc"/>
    <img src="img3.jpg" class="thumbnail img-responsive etc etc"/>
    <img src="img4.jpg" class="thumbnail img-responsive etc etc"/>
    <img src="img5.jpg" class="thumbnail img-responsive etc etc"/>
</div>
```

Have anyone feel this inconvenient? I feel having to do this sort of steers away from the need which stylesheet emerges from: to *separate* style from structure and avoid repetition.

I wish I could select all the **img** in **#foo**, and give all of them a same set of class.I believe there ought to be a way of doing this, only that I don't know. Any ideas folks?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make use of the framework's CSS preprocessor (e.g. [Less](http://lesscss.org/features/), [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), etc.)

In Less, your example could be:

```
@import "bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
#foo img {
  .thumbnail;
  .img-responsive;
}
```

Comment: The other js solution also works, however I think this can be a more permanent and safe approach because there won't be an issue of js being disabled by the browser. Am I right? I'm looking into Less right now. Thanks!

Comment: @bilibili You normally use Less/Sass/etc. in your dev environment or on your server, **not client-side**. Read the getting started docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with jQuery. It would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#foo img').addClass('classname');
)};
```

Comment: I tried it an it easily worked! Thanks! Next time I try something like changing between different styling I'd definitely use this method. I wish I have enough rep to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

In your `<head>`, load your bootstrap CSS first:

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Then load a custom CSS file

```
<link href="css/my_custom_css.css" rel="stylesheet"> //assumes you have a css folder and then name your file, in this example it's named my_custom_css.css
```

In your custom file define your custom CSS

```
#foo img { //will affect img under id="foo"
   margin: 0px; //just an example
   //whatever styles you want to define
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what really has been bothering me is to assign class to elements(in order to use pre-defined styles from Bootstrap), rather than give my own style to them.

Comment: That's why PHP and other object oriented languages make this easier.  You can have an array with your image names and then echo them using a loop where you only have to write the class names once.