# Making all tables use the same bootstrap classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I want every table for my website to have the same bootstrap styling with

```
class="table table-striped table-hover "
```

However I don't really want to go into every table and put this in in case I want to change it in future.  Is there a way for me to just set,

```
.table{
  /*Inherit all these classes*/
}
```

Comment: You can achieve this by using Less or Sass. See an Less example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use LESS or SASS and make a mix-in for this. If you can't use LESS/SASS, you could overwrite `.table` as follows if you absolutely needed to, using something like this (pulled from BS 3.2):

```
/* .table-stripe styling */
.table > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td, 
.table > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th{
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

/* Default .table-hover behavior */
.table > tbody > tr:hover > td,
.table > tbody > tr:hover > th {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

/* .table-hover styling for "active". 
    Repeat this block for Success, Info, Warning, Danger, etc. 
    using your preferred colors */
.table > tbody > tr > td.active:hover,
.table > tbody > tr > th.active:hover,
.table > tbody > tr.active:hover > td,
.table > tbody > tr:hover > .active,
.table > tbody > tr.active:hover > th {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You potentially could try combining all the rules from the

```
table table-striped table-hover
```

classes into one class, **but** you also need to capture the rulesets targeted by `table table-striped table-hover`  `child` and `descendant` selectors also.
So in the end you will end up creating way more work for yourself.

e.g. if you look at the boostrap CSS source here - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L255

```
  .table {
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
  }
  .table td,
  .table th {
    background-color: #fff !important;
  }
  .table-bordered th,
  .table-bordered td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
  }
}
```

these sub rules would also need to be rewritten.
I've shown **3** CSS rules.
If you do a search for the term `.table` in the bootstrap CSS there are **318** instances which would need to be resolved.

You could reduce that by compiling your own LESS or SASS, but you will still have to deal with the `child` and `descendant` issue.

#### Possible solution

If you have a decent text editor, that using live templates or something like emmet, just create a short cut like `tab+` which the text editor expands out to  `table table-striped table-hover`