# Can we state multiple parent CSS classes, while the children remain the same?

Tags: css

As we know, there's several CSS shortcuts (greater than, classes joined without spacing etc. etc.) but I'm wondering if we can state multiple parent CSS classes, while the children remain the same ?

For ease, I'm using a simple example...

Instead of:

```
.node-type-sponsors .container .page-header, 
.node-type-supporters .container .page-header 
{color:blue;}
```

Is there a shorter way of writing this by specifying the parent classes to be affected, but only listing the children once...

eg:

```
.node-type-sponsors,.node-type-supporters 
[I assume something would go here to signify we've moved onto child elements] 
.container .page-header 
{color:blue;}
```

Comment: Can you not just add another class to the html elements required and reference that instead?

Comment: Not with CSS.. a pre-processor.language like SASS/LESS might be able to do that but it's still going to output the same CSS. In other words the pre-processor will make **writing** the CSS quicker but it won't reduce the output result.

Comment: No, it isn't possible. In this case you can *probably* use `.container .page-header` without parent definition. If not, there is no way how to make your code shorter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a CSS class inherit one or more other classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isnt possible with out sass/less etc

As an hack **if you have exactly  same scenario** that `you have a pattern matching in an class name either at start or end` you can do something like, you can see for starting match attribute

```
 [class^="node-type"] .container{}
```

**Working Demo:**

```css
[class^="node-type"] .container{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="node-type-sponsors">
  <p class="container ">abc</p>
 </div>
<div class="node-type-supporters">
  <p class="container">abc</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: In your example `[class^="node-type"]` defines only those classes that are starting with `node-type`

Comment: @balintpekker i wrote in answer that if you have exactly this matching pattern then you can try this

Comment: You are right. I just said it before you added explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In this snippet, every `<p>` element that has a parent of `div`, or `span` with the specified classes got yellow background. You are looking for the `>` combinator.

```css
.this-is-a-div, .this-is-a-span > p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<span class="this-is-a-span">
<p>Paragraph in a span.</p>
</span>

<div class="this-is-a-div">
<p>Paragraph 1 in the div.</p>
<p>Paragraph 2 in the div.</p>
</div>

<p>Paragraph 3. Not in a div.</p>
<p>Paragraph 4. Not in a div.</p>
```

You can read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp). Hope that helps.