# What are the default CSS styling of heading tags? (H1, h2, h3, h4, h5)

Tags: html, css

In HTML, headings are denoted with `<H>`(1,2,3,4,5,6) tag.

My question is regarding following HTML code:

```
<div class="pure-u-1-1 pure-u-lg-3-3">
    <h3><form:label path="gen">Registrer Bruker</form:label></h3>
</div>
```

Instead of writing `<H3>`, i want to write property of class in CSS ; which gives same font size (look and feel); as of heading HTML gives. Also is there predefined property for same in CSS?

Comment: Please fix your grammar, it's difficult to understand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a CSS class inherit one or more other classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes)

Comment: @fauverism Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I don't think CSS itself has anything 'predefined' does it? You would just create your own rules for the classes.

Comment: @Lee
May be term predefined is wrong. Here i mean Just like font-weight, font-size, width, height, is there any like header-1 or big-header or i need classes only?

Comment: @JBux
I don't find answer there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browsers' default CSS for HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The answer is no, however you might hack the styles. Most browsers will try to use these styles

(Taken from: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp))

```
h1 { 
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.67em;
    margin-bottom: 0.67em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h2 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 0.83em;
    margin-bottom: 0.83em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h3 { 
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.17em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h4 { 
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1.33em;
    margin-bottom: 1.33em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h5 { 
    display: block;
    font-size: .83em;
    margin-top: 1.67em;
    margin-bottom: 1.67em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h6 { 
    display: block;
    font-size: .67em;
    margin-top: 2.33em;
    margin-bottom: 2.33em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Missing: h4 font-size: 1em

Comment: By definition all text has a `font-size` of `1em`; ... `1em` basically means "100% normal  text size".  Since it's the default, there isn't any need to specify it with a CSS rule.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there predefined property for same in CSS; which gives same look and feel as H gives?

No.

The default style of a heading is (in most browsers) exactly that: a *collection* of different CSS rules coupled with an `Hn` selector (and stored in the browser stylesheet).

There isn't a (plain CSS) way to automatically copy all of those rules.

You could use the Inspector tool that comes in the developer tools built into most browsers to examine a heading and look at the default rules for it, and then copy those rules to your own (author) stylesheet.

There may be some variations between browsers, so you'll generally want to set the `Hn` rules explicitly too.

Comment: You could use javascript. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element/6416527#6416527

Answer (score -2):

> Question: is there predefined property for same in CSS?

No

You can try like this:

```
h3{ 
   display: block; 
}

h3 {
   font-size: /*Font size similar to h3*/ ;
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Think a good practice is let h<1-6> keep their default styles. And then add a class to add additional styles. Just seems cleaner to me, and you are not hacking the "master styles." Pros and Cons I'm sure.

<h1 class="h1">Hello CSS</h1>