# Is it just me or is the "revert" value in css a bit random?

Tags: html, css

```css
#sec {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: royalblue;
}

#id1 {
  font-size: revert;
  font-weight: revert;
  color: revert;
}

#id2 {
  font-size: unset;
  font-weight: unset;
  color: unset;
}
```

```html
<section id="sec">
    <h3 id="id1">hello revert</h3>
    <h3 id="id2">hello unset</h3>
</section>
```

Inheritance for #id1 worked for all properties with revert except for font-weight, here it just takes the UA Style. Maybe someone can explain why only font-weight don't inherit since font-size and font-weight both have default styling accoring to here: [What are the default CSS styling of heading tags? (H1, h2, h3, h4, h5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30980873/what-are-the-default-css-styling-of-heading-tags-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5)

Comment: inheritance is working only for color. Font-size is not inherited but is using the default value 1.17em AND em means use the parent font-size (you have an illusion of inheritance but it's not)

Comment: ^ only color is inherited because the UA is not defining any default color to Headings