# I want one word in my title/h1 to read horizontally and the second to read vertically

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and want the first word in my title/h1 tag to be read horizontally and the second word to be read vertically.

I tried using span tags in my h1 but it would only let my change the color and would not work when I used the rotate feature.

html

```
<h1>
    <span class="horizontal-QuanT">QuanT</span>
    <span class="verticle-Tech">Tech</span>
</h1>
```

css

```
h1{
color:bisque;
text-align: center;} 

h1 span.horizontal-QuanT{
color:gray} 

h1 span.verticle-Tech{
color:white;
rotate: 90deg;}
```

Comment: Please update with the actual HTML and CSS that you have tried IN the question    This may assist you in a better quality question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss fixed, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline elements can't be rotated, so you need to set `display: inline-block;` on the vertical span. Also, the correct syntax for rotating is `transform: rotate(90deg);`.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
} 

h1 span.horizontal-QuanT {
  color: gray;
} 

h1 span.vertical-Tech {
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<h1>
    <span class="horizontal-QuanT">QuanT</span>
    <span class="vertical-Tech">Tech</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Might suggest just changing the `<span>` to a `<div>` and just drop the extra `display` in the CSS  since this is effectively what this does perhaps.

Comment: Then again content for `<h1>` is "phrasing content" which this then breaks either way and thus the `<h1>` should also become a div perhaps that is styled using CSS the same as an H1 tag ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30980873/125981

Comment: `<span>` is permitted in phrasing content, `<div>` is not -- so the markup is correct as written. Note that by default, a `<span>` has the style `display: inline;`, but if we want to rotate it we need to style it as `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have really kind of gotten away from the semantic meaning of the tags I would suggest you just use three div styled as a grid and give yourself full control of the style without working around the CSS of an `h1` tag.

Feel free to change margins padding etc. to set each part where you want including the size of the header container.

Note: I did NOT use the tags like div, span etc. in the CSS as I consider that a bad practice so you can change the element tag without also needing to change the CSS.

```css
.my-header-container {
  background-color: #0000FF22;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 6rem 2rem;
  grid-template-rows: 3.5em;
  font-size: 2em;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: start;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F2D2BD;
}

.my-header-container .horizontal-container {
  grid-column: 1;
  color: #808080;
  display: inline-block;
}

.my-header-container .verticle-container {
  grid-column: 2;
  margin-top: 1em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  rotate: 90deg;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-header-container">
  <div class="horizontal-container">QuanT</div>
  <div class="verticle-container">Tech</div>
</div>
```