# How to create css classes from existing ones?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a class, for example, **.myTable**, that includes several existing Bootstrap classes, like **table table-striped table-hover**, so that i can apply this single new class to all my tables. How do I accomplish that please?

ashilon

Comment: you need to use tools like LESS
for more information see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes

Comment: Either give the tables the appropriate class or update the selector(s) to match your table. There is no way in plain CSS to 'add a selector' after the definition.

Comment: Thanks guys, both answers were helpful to me.