# Custom class for Bootstrap Buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can you define a custom class to create bootstrap buttons.

In my theme I have

- Edit Button

  `<a class='btn btn-flat bg-green btn-xs' href='...'>Edit</a>`
- Delete Button

  `<a class='btn btn-flat bg-red btn-xs' href='...'>Edit</a>`

Can I use a single class for each that imports the styles without having to redefine the style code.

ex:

`<a class='btn-app-edit' href='...'>Edit</a>`

Is there a css function that can do this ?
ex:

```
.btn-app-edit:inherit('btn btn-flat bg-green');
```

Having a feature like this means that when the master theme is replaced or changes from bootstrap to another css framework, my custom classes can just link up to the new Css framework rather than having to change the implementation everywhere.

Comment: How about using LESS?

Comment: Thought of that. I havnt used LESS as of yet. Just hoping for a simple Css3 function. If not may have to use LESS

Comment: There is no inheritance in css. Like Maroun suggested, use `less` to acheive. `less` uses js and has quite some handy functions like `import` and stuff and you can reuse class. Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1065476/2196341

Comment: thanks, I'm looking up less now. I can definitely see the benefits. Ill setup my environment for less and start converting my main theme file. blah

Comment: looking at less, would I use mixing? ex: `.mybutton {.btn .btn-flat}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a CSS class inherit one or more other classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes)