# Is there a way to share common CSS classes?

Tags: css

I have 5 CSS classes. They are completely identical except one line. Is there a way to create one CSS class, then have the 5 other CSS classes inherite from the one and just add it's own specific's?

As you can see below the only line that is different is this line...

background-image: url("../Images/vertTabsButton2.gif");

```
.divMasterCol1Button1 {
  float: left;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: thin;
  background-image: url("../Images/vertTabsButton1.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: top;
  width: 215px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.divMasterCol1Button2 {
  float: left;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: thin;
  background-image: url("../Images/vertTabsButton2.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: top;
  width: 215px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful: [Can a CSS class inherit one or more other classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes)

Comment: Use standard CSS rules, see my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your HTML

```
<button class="commonProperties divMasterCol1Button1"/>
<button class="commonProperties divMasterCol1Button2"/>
```

Here's your CSS

```
.commonProperties {
  float: left;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: thin;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: top;
  width: 215px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.divMasterCol1Button2 {
  background-image: url("http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg");
}

.divMasterCol1Button1 {
  background-image: url("http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg");
}
```

Comment: I like this answer. It shows the css and html. Thank you. I'll try it monday. It's Saturday right now and I'm practicing relaxing.

Answer (score 5):

Without using a [pre-compiler like SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) you cannot achieve inheritance. However you could accomplish *something* like what you want by splitting the common properties out into a single class and applying the remaining unique properties through some other ID or class.

```
.commonProperties {
  float: left;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: thin;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: top;
  width: 215px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.divMasterCol1Button2 {
  background-image: url("../Images/vertTabsButton2.gif");
}

.divMasterCol1Button1 {
  background-image: url("../Images/vertTabsButton2.gif");
}
```

Comment: Just about to post this. For clarity, if you wanted `.divMasterCol1Button1` to have different backgrounds depending on the class it was paired with, you could do `.commonProperties.divMasterCol1Button1 { ... }`.

Comment: Can't you do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/v11twkfL/1/)?  This example doesn't use an extra class.  Only CSS properties that are defined override existing properties for the same class.

Comment: You can have more CSS per class defined, see my post.

Comment: @UltraSonja Absolutely, however what you are demonstrating is not strictly _inheritance_, but _cascading_.

Comment: Why would someone want to use inheritance in CSS anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using SASS or LESS. Here's an example of it would look like for both pre-compiler languages with your class

SCSS

```
.divMasterCol1Button1 {
  float: left;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: thin;
  background-image: url("../Images/vertTabsButton1.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: top;
  width: 215px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.divMasterCol1Button2 {
     @extend .divMasterCol1Button1;
     background-image: url("../Images/vertTabsButton2.gif");
}
```

and here is LESS

```
.divMasterCol1Button1 {
  float: left;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: thin;
  background-image: url("../Images/vertTabsButton1.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: top;
  width: 215px;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.divMasterCol1Button2 {
    .divMasterCol1Button1;
    background-image: url("../Images/vertTabsButton2.gif");
}
```

I prefer SCSS because bootstrap 4 is beginning to use it for their framework.....

Answer (score 1):

Simply use CSS:

```
.c1,.c2,.c3,.c4,.c5{
  //common styles
}
.c1{
  //c1 special style
}
...
.c5{
  //c5 special style
}
```

See example http://jsfiddle.net/qj76455e/

I wanted to make the principle readable, therefore I used short class names c1,...,c5 instead of divMasterCol1Button1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 or more classes. OOCSS, SMACSS or BEM will be great tool.

.button {
...
}

.button--red { color: red; }

Or you can achieve this with @extend operator in sass, less or stylus.