# Add CSS class y to elements of class x?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wondering if there is a pure CSS way to add a class to elements of another class. The problem I'm trying to solve is below, which is also an example.

Using bootstrap, I have a number of elements that look like this:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Law</a>
</li>
```

What I would like to do is add the `pull-right` class to each element with the class `nav-item` (I think), in order to make the nav items all float to the right.

Is there a pure CSS way to do this? I *think* the answer is no, [at least without LESS/SASS/JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes), but I'd love to be disabused of that notion.

Comment: Yea sorry to say, you can't add a class without JS. The closest functionality that I know of that is CSS only is to use the pseudo-class hover or focus or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you are wanting to add a class to the CSS you would need to use either JavaScript or Jquery.  I would recommend Jquery because IMO it is a little easier to work with when adding classes.

Or you could just add the class to each nav-item:

```
<li class="nav-item pull-right">
```