# Combining Classes in CSS and Not HTML

Tags: html, css, sass, gulp

Is there a  tool out there that allows you to combine CSS classes? It seems handy to combine them in something like Tailwind css, but is there a way to "add them up" in the css? Sass has the @extend which is similar to what I'm thinking. But is there something out there that looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="author"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {with: 100px; height: 100px;}
.green (background-color: green}

.author { .card + .green }
```

or maybe

```
.author = .card.green
```

Then with more classes, it'd end up something like:

```
.author, 
.staff, 
.jockey = .card.green.padding-large.centered.motif-top
```

Does this exist?

Comment: CSS-in-js allows you to use the spread operator to do things like this.

Comment: You can't do it in pure CSS, but using Less would work just like that. I'll answer showing you how to do so with Less.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a CSS class inherit one or more other classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes)

Comment: It's possible in CSS. Less will be compiled to CSS, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so with the help of [Less.css](http://lesscss.org). Just add this `<script>` tag to your HTML file:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.7.1/less.min.js" ></script>
```

And add a `<link>` to an external stylesheet like this (this is not needed, but Less is less buggy if written in an external file `.less` rather than inside `<style>` tags in HTML):

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
```

Now, this example you provided:

```
.card {width: 100px; height: 100px;}
.green (background-color: green}

.author { .card + .green }
```

Can be written in Less as:

```
.card {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
}

.author {
    .card();
    .green();
}
```

And the second example of:

```
.author, 
.staff, 
.jockey = .card.green.padding-large.centered.motif-top
```

Is written in Less like:

```
.author, .staff, .jockey {
    .card();
    .green();
    .padding-large();
    .centered();
    .motif-top();
}
```

Hopefully this helped you, and go to the [official website](http://lesscss.org) to learn more about Less CSS (**Le**arner **S**tyle **S**heets)

Answer (score 2):

This is the pure CSS way, but syntax is slightly different and you don't need the first line:

```css
.author {} /* 1st line is not required*/

.author, .class1 {
  width: 100px;
}
.author, .class2 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="author"><div>
```

More Information here: [Can a CSS class inherit one or more other classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes)