# Change PageTemplate style depending on the page slot in Spartacus

Tags: css, spartacus-storefront

Hi Spartacus experts,

I have created a PageTemplate called `xyz` via Impex, in frontend the `cx-page-layout` element will receive the class `xyz`, but how can I add additional classes to this `cx-page-layout` element? I use the template for 2 cases (each case uses a different `cx-page-slot` and it would be great to apply different CSS styles to the `cx-page-layout` with `xyz` class depending on which case is being applied.

It is important to say that the style is supposed to be applied to the PageTemplate in CSS, not the slots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to solve the original issue relies on CSS purely. As it is just a issue of positioning: I added `display: flex` so I can apply the `align-items: center` to the `cx-page-slot` called `EmptyCartCenterContent`, while other `cx-page-slot` was not affected by it.

```
.CartPageTemplate{
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  padding: map_get($spacers, 6) 0 0 0;
  max-width: none;

  .EmptyCartCenterContent {
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be better to apply classes to the page template class in your css? Adding classes to dynamically rendered `<cx-page-layout>` elements doesn't seem like a good idea and you already have a class available as a way to modify the page template styling through inheritance.

Here are a few ways to inherit properties depending on if/which preprocessor you are using: [Can a CSS class inherit one or more other classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes)

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer! I need to apply different styles to the class for `cx-page-layout`, depending on the class in the child element `cx-page-slot`, it is not possible through CSS/SCSS, I thought maybe there is a way to do this within Spartacus :)