# How to simplify repeating lines in CSS blocks?

Tags: css, coding-style, less

It must be a simple question, but the answer is not clear to me. I would like something simple. If I have these two CSS blocks, 1, 2, can I simplify so that the same lines are not repeated? As you noticed, only the color changes in them.

```css
.glass-btn-main {/* 1 */
    background-color: #2961B6;
    border: solid 1px #2961B6;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    padding: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.glass-btn-secundary { /* 2 */
    background-color: transparent;
    border: solid 1px #2961B6;
    color: #2961B6;
    padding: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a shared class like `.glass-btn`

Comment: I'd say you have 2 options, use a shared class like @DanielA.White suggested or if you're using a preprocessor like SCSS you can use `@extend`. Check this out [extend](https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/)

Comment: [Can a CSS class inherit one or more other classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1065435)

Comment: TXS Johnny. The simple solution I was looking for is: <div class="firstClass secondClass thirdclass fourthclass"></div>