# Inherit Bootstrap table stripe color

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

My Razor component populates a number of divs to a container.

Is it possible to inherit the table-stripe color and apply it to my divs (odd) rather than overriding it?

Or, if I declared a new CSS class "Div-Stripe-Row".

Is it possible to reference the background-color from Bootstrap's table-striped background-color (use what's already there) rather than declaring a new color (overriding it by just copying what the color is)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately, CSS does not provide 'inheritance' in the way that programming languages like C++, C#, or Java do. You can't declare a CSS class and then extend it with another CSS class.

> However, you can apply more than a single class to a tag in your markup ... in which case there is a sophisticated set of rules that determine which actual styles will get applied by the browser.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1065476/3842598

The accepted answer says:

> There are tools like LESS, which allow you to compose CSS at a higher level of abstraction similar to what you describe.

> Less calls these "Mixins"
> ...

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1065476/3842598

Comment: Thanks @Christian, a very precise answer to what I was looking for. A little out of scope of this post, but can you tell me what the inherit keyword in CSS actually does? I do recall seeing it back when Bootstrap wasn't as popular.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit

Answer (score 1):

Your question may be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065435/can-a-css-class-inherit-one-or-more-other-classes).

Unless you want to use LESS, I would recommend adding a class to those divs and copy the styles of the Razor component to that class.

Comment: I wanted to avoid overriding the attributes (creating a completely new class with separate colors), as at some point I might want to change themes and wouldn't want to go through every where I'm adding changes. Is there a way to create a new class and inherit the background-color thats used by Bootstrap defined table-stripe class?

Comment: Read over the question I linked to, but in short, no, you can't inherit classes with CSS.