# Using Compass on Windows with Visual Studio C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, visual-studio, compass-sass

Has anyone done any development of Compass for CSS/SASS in a standard C# ASP.NET environment?

Is there a single distribution I can just download that's ready to go for Windows or do I need install every piece of the equation and build compass myself?

Are there any plugins that make developing with Compass friendlier with VS2008 such as automagical handling of Compass/SASS in builds, syntax highlighting, and/or intellisense support?

If there aren't any VS IDE plugins what are the best options for a standalone text editor for handling coding in Compass?

Comment: This was also an answer but was deleted for some reason: http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Getting-Started-with-SASS-for-Microsoft-Developers.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To complete the last answers, you can install [**Web Workbench**](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench), a plugin for Visual Studio 2010 wich add **syntax highlighting**, **intellisence** and some other stuff for the SASS language (SCSS syntax only).

If you prefer using Compass and/or some other tools to compile your CSS, you should disable the built-in compiler. I listed some other SASS compilers here: [Using SASS with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796788/using-sass-with-asp-net/8981789#8981789).

<strike>To disable the built-in compiler: select the .scss file in Solution Explorer, go to the Properties window and delete the text from the Custom Tool box.</strike>

Since Web Workbench 3 you can now manage more easily what you want to compile with this plugin. See the Mindscape > Web Workbench Settings menu item.

Comment: I just tried using the Compass .scss files but encountered a NoMethodError for a '>' in the code. Did you get Web Workbench to play well with Compass?

Comment: I use it every day with the Compass compiler, and it works fine. Did you install the last version? Did you remove the custom tool in the file properties? Are you sure there isn't an another plugin in VS that create a conflict?

Answer (score 6):

Getting started with Compass,

First yes I have to install Ruby and the compass source and compile up my version of compass I followed the instructions on Compass's Wiki [Getting Started](http://wiki.github.com/chriseppstein/compass/getting-started).

After getting Compass and all it's dependencies installed and built I created my first project.

```
compass -f blueprint project-name
```

Which creates a default project with compass for the blueprint css framework, currently there's a bug in compass with the creation of the grid.png file in the images directory for compass so you need to copy the original grid.png from the source folder

```
C:\Ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\chriseppstein-compass-0.8.10
    \frameworks\blueprint\templates\project
```

Or similarly located file depending on where you installed everything. One of the most important changes IMO for working with compass on asp.net is to change the SASS CACHE directive of compass. The SASS CACHE creates a bunch of temporary folders in your project directory which probably would have poor outcomes if they ended under source control. So open up config.rb and add this line

```
sass_options = {:cache_location => 
    "#{Compass.configuration.project_path}\\tmp\\sass-cache"}
```

Make sure to note the escaped backslashs.

After this I modified the names of the folders that compass uses for how I wanted them named inside the config.rb and started getting to it with SASS and Compass. I recommend watching the hour long introduction to compass video it's very helpful and I learned alot from it: [Watch the screen cast](http://wiki.github.com/chriseppstein/compass).

One of the things which this showed me was how to set compass to watch for file system changes and automagic compile the sass to css. By using

```
compass -w
```

This is working real well for me, just make sure you keep your css files checked out or turn them off read only if they're under source control if your project doesn't support concurrent checkouts.

For editing I'm using SciTE that's included with Ruby by default for the config.rb files or just the editor window in VS2008. For Sass I came across a big list on the [HAML website](http://groups.google.com/group/haml/web/syntax-highlighting). jEdit with highlighting syntax file for SASS was what I ended up using after trying a few. I'd still like to find a VS plugin for syntax highlighting so I don't need to use another editor but jEdit is definitely getting the job done.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is a bit antiquated. Before following my original answer, I would recommend exploring the Nuget package [SassAndCoffee. The full details can be found here](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2011/05/16/announcing-sassandcoffee-0-5/).

> How does it work?
>
> SassAndCoffee embeds the original
>   compilers in the DLL as (Sass 3.2.0
>   and CoffeeScript 1.1.0 as of this
>   writing) and uses IronRuby and
>   Jurassic respectively to execute the
>   compilers against your source.
>
> Why is
>   this better than [SOMEOTHERPROJECT]?
>
> ```
> No external processes are executed
> You don’t have to install Ruby or node.js
> It’s in NuGet so you don’t have to fiddle with web.config
> Files are cached and are rebuilt as-needed.
> ```

Comment: SassAndCoffee isn't ready for Compass yet, Compass actually patches the Sass compiler to do extra stuff. It's the next big feature that SassAndCoffee will support though!

Comment: @PaulBetts is Compass integration still in the pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add another alternative here. If you just want to ensure that compass builds the sass files and includes the css files when you build your ASP.net project you can add the following to your project(csproj) file under the project section:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
   <Exec Command="compass compile --output-style compressed --force" />
   <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="Styles\*.css" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterCompile" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <Exec Command="compass compile" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="Styles\*.css" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

The first Target is for Release and will also compress the css, the other one is for Debug.

If you want to customize paths add a config.rb to the project root folder:

```
css_dir = "Content"
sass_dir = "Content/Sass"
```

This all of course requires compass and ruby to be installed and to be in the path of your machine.

Comment: Only downside is this slowing down your builds even when it didn't need to compile, probably not very impactful if you don't have tons of SASS/SCSS files