# Is there a css "compiler" that auto expands to cover all/most browsers?

Tags: css

Specifically looking at things with a -webkit, -moz -o prefix such as transform, transition, etc...

I'm wanting something like a [smart sass](http://sass-lang.com/) (which I thought would probably do it, but doesn't appear to) that would take the generic form of commands and write all the long prefixed versions for me.  For example:

```
    .shrink {
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
        -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
        -o-transform: scale(0);
    }
```

would be written as

```
    .shrink {
        transition: transform 1s;
        transform: scale(0);
    }
```

and the css "compiler" would write out all the other stuff.....

Comment: i dont think so, but there are things like this: http://css3generator.com

Answer (score 4):

## 2018 edit

I'd use https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer with webpack to accomplish the sort of "css compiling" asked about in the original question

---

## original 2011 answer

Here's one:
http://www.techievideos.com/videos/1152/Save-time-writting-vendor-prefixes-using-CSS3-and-LESS/

---

Another option that would accomplish the goal:

It's a css3 converter that generates a background image that is served up to non-compliant/old browsers. Worth a look!

http://www.css3toimage.com/

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

[SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) + [Compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/) will get you what you want (as long as you don't mind Ruby / command line compilation.)

Here's an example from one of [Compass' example pages](http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/background-clip/):

**SCSS:**

```
    @include background-clip(padding-box);

    @include background-clip(border-box);
```

These expand to:

```
-moz-background-clip: padding;
-webkit-background-clip: padding;
-o-background-clip: padding-box;
-ms-background-clip: padding-box;
-khtml-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;

/* And */

-moz-background-clip: border;
-webkit-background-clip: border;
-o-background-clip: border-box;
-ms-background-clip: border-box;
-khtml-background-clip: border-box;
background-clip: border-box;
```

Comment: Also if your on a asp.net environment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796788/using-sass-with-asp-net

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://css-infos.net/properties/webkit.php) you find an amount of webkit css attributes. Most of them are similar to -o or -moz!

Comment: right, most are "similar" I don't want to have to keep up with which ones, I want to say it once and have a tool deal with it.....