# Sass and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sass

is there a way to use Sass with asp.net where you can use variables that are stored in the database and then are compiled by Sass for the final css file?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796788/using-sass-with-asp-net

Comment: No because there is no clear answer to the question without using ports or any other workarounds.

Comment: Fair enough, I did flag it "possible". However, in your question you should mention if you've looked at other answers and found them lacking (with specifics as to what was lacking) so that people don't repeat themselves when answering yours. A clear set of requirements when asking for recommendations is key to not only getting the correct answer, but also to help guide the discussion.